# How create Binding on Property between two classes

Tags: c#, binding

I got a class vertex which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. So I have for example two different instances of the vertex class and I need to bind from instance a the weight property to instance b to the weight property.

```
public class Vertex : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
            [...]
    #region Members
            <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Weight of the vertex
    /// </summary>
    public int Weight { get { return weight; } set { weight = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Weight"); } }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
            [...]
}
```

I tried to use System.Windows.Data.Binding to create a binding between instance a and b but I can't set the binding because there is not SetBinding Method on the class vertex. So is there a right solution for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by binding between two properties?

Comment: do you mean for instance A.Weight = B.weight;

Comment: "do you mean for instance A.Weight = B.weight;" yes

Comment: If the A.Weight Propertie Value changes the Propertie B.Weight should be automatically updated.